# Best way to mock Kafka on junit test?

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, apache-kafka

I have a spring boot application that uses a Kafka consumer and producer. All the configuration of Kafka is on the application.yml

```
spring:
    kafka:
        consumer:
            enable-auto-commit: true
            key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
            value-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
            bootstrap-servers: kafka.dev-streams.svc.cluster.local:9092
            group-id: dev.client
        producer:
            bootstrap-servers: kafka-0.kafka-headless.dev-streams.svc.cluster.local:9092,kafka-1.kafka-headless.dev-streams.svc.cluster.local:9092,kafka-2.kafka-headless.dev-streams.svc.cluster.local:9092
            key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
            value-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
            retries: 3
```

Example of one consumer:

```
        @KafkaListener(topics = { "${kafka.topic.internal.request}" })
        @Override
        public void processRequest(@Payload String message,
                        @Header(name = KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_MESSAGE_KEY, required = false) String key) {
                super.processRequest(message, key);
        }
```

How can i mock kafka to get some message on the consumer using a Junit test and not use the bootstrap-server ?

Comment: Does the [testing section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#testing) of the docs help?

Comment: Not much. It still don't solve my problem.

Comment: Why not? It shows how you can test a consumer

Answer (score 1):

You can use embedded Kafka it's in-memory Kafka broker that runs during the test.
here some articles on how to use it:

- https://blog.mimacom.com/testing-apache-kafka-with-spring-boot-junit5/
- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-kafka-testing